# Open Browser from C# Desktop Application and catch parameters in webpage

Tags: javascript, c#, html, web

I have a desktop form built in C# that has a text field and a button. When user enters his/her name inside textbox (e.g. John) and presses enter, a browser window should be opened and it should display "Hello, John". Please tell me how Desktop Form will send argument (John) and webpage will catch it to show. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is the code in C# to open up a browser given a URL:

```
Process.Start("explorer.exe", "https://yoursite?name=John");
```

Then in your web page you should read that `name` argument from the query String, here's how you can do it in JS:

```
var name = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('name');
```